# Есть ли в предложении речевая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли речевая ошибка в предложении: «Строим планы для будущих благ»? Если да, то как будет верно и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Есть. Возможно, даже не одна. Они связаны с неправильным употреблением фразеологизма "строить планы" – тут и объект не тот, и предлог неправильный.

Планы можно "строить" **на что** (на будущее, например) – и то в крайне ограниченном контексте – помимо планов на будущее, это могут быть планы каких-то действий.
При другом использовании надо или слово "строим" заменить на другой глагол, либо вообще от предлога отказаться: получим что-то вроде "разрабатываем планы мероприятия".

Таким образом, если говорить о благах и не отказываться от конструкции "строим планы", минимальная правка будет такой:
***строим планы на получение будущих благ*** (а ещё лучше "грядущих" – если контекст позволяет)
или же
***строим планы получения благ в будущем*** – хотя это, пожалуй, несколько хуже в силу неоднозначности.

П.С. Предлагаемая замена на предлог "по" мне не нравится – мало того, что такое использование предлога (в значении сферы применения) уже само по себе не самый высокий стиль, так еще и с предметом не соотносится. Впрочем, это тот уровень стилистики, где любое мнение будет субъективным, так что не настаиваю.

И что уж точно не нравится – так это "достижение благ". Это само по себе можно считать стилистической ошибкой, ибо "достигают" **успеха**, а "блага" **получают** и пользуются ими.

Answer (score 0):

Словосочетание "будущие блага" означает, что блага будут в будущем независимо от наших действий. Оно будет ошибкой в данном контексте.

Предлог "для" может обозначать цель, если добавить глагольное существительное:
"Строим планы для достижения благ в будущем".
Однако, эта цель будет не у планов, а у строительства планов.
Формально, ошибки нет: построение плана приближает нас к его выполнению.
Стилистическая ошибка в смещении акцента с цели планов, на построение планов.
Правильно:

```
Строим планы достижения благ в будущем. 
Строим планы, как достигнуть благ, на будущее. 
Строим планы по достижению благ в будущем.
```

"блага в будущем" это тоже блага независимые от контекста, но только если "в будущем" определение у "благ", а у нас не так.